# Are there any InterContinental Hotels Group (IHG) properties in Sri Lanka?

Tags: loyalty-programs, sri-lanka

I'm looking at doing a mattress run / mileage run for my [IHG Rewards Club](https://www.ihg.com/rewardsclub/us/en/home) account while I'm travelling in Sri Lanka later this month. However, on the IHG site I can't find any rooms for dates in cities like Colombo, Kandi etc.

Are there any IHG properties at all in Sri Lanka? I can't see any easy way on the IHG site to find a list of all properties in a country.

Comment: If you're after a cheap night to qualify for Accelerate, check on flyertalk as there's a fair bit of discussion there on the cheapest hotels especially near airports. Note that you will have to check in in person - just booking isn't enough!

Comment: @Gagravarr I've already obtained the bonuses for Accelerate 2015 (and I have enough time for Accelerate 2016 on business trips). I was actually looking to get IHG Platinum before 11 January 2016 to get [status-matched to HHonors Diamond](http://thepointsguy.com/2015/11/hilton-status-through-march-2017/)

Comment: Platinum is a bit "meh" in many (but not all) IHG hotels, so I wouldn't suggest getting it for the benefits - and I say that as someone who's now made Spire! The bonus points packages normally post as elite-qualifying, if you're trying to qualify on points booking one with 5k or 10k bonus is your easiest. If you're going on nights, and you can't just short-circuit the process by getting the right credit card, check flyertalk for cheap hotels!

Comment: Also, be aware that Hilton seems to give out Gold and Diamond like candy to holders of their US-only credit card, so in US and Canadian hotels Diamond doesn't get you very much. It's certainly worth having in Europe and Asia, sadly much less valuable in the USA due to the sheer numbers of "plastic diamonds" in the system...

Comment: Last one was "Ceylon Continental Hotel Colombo", now it is called "The Kingsbury Hotel" and it belongs to a different group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, sorry.

[They have a list of the 100 or so countries on their website](http://www.ihg.com/destinations/us/en/explore).

(scroll down to see them)

Unfortunately, Sri Lanka is not listed among them.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up! Did stumble across that page. I was confused by the [list of IHG Reservation Offices around the world](https://www.ihg.com/hotels/us/en/customer-care/worldwide-reservation-offices) which quoted a number in Sri Lanka, so I assumed they might have some presence there.